# ConsumeEvent (blocking=true) is running on executor-thread

Tags: quarkus

Quarkus Version 2.1.2.Final

When running in quarkusDev everything is running in the correct thread (vert.x-worker-thread-x) and is even obeying the `quarkus.vertx.worker-pool-size` property as I would expect.

When running the quarkus-app that is built from the build task I am seeing the thread of execution as (executor-thread-x).

Not sure why the thread of execution is changing when running the application after it's been built vs running in quarkusDev. As an aside I am using the exact same properties for both the quarkusDev and running the output of the build task.

I have created a sample project that showcases the above described issue. (https://github.com/owlkaboom/quarkus-threading-question) This sample project uses 2.2.1-final since I wanted to see if this was resolved in a later release.

You will notice it "submits 500" items into an eventbus which when you run it with quarkusDev you will notice it is actually using the worker-threads correctly and obeying the pool size limits.

When you build and run via `java -jar` you will now notice it does not obey worker-threads and just runs on the executor-thread instead.

Answer (score 0):

The above mentioned issue is not expected behavior. Opened a new GitHub issue (https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/19911).

This is not expected behavior and once the GitHub issue has been resolved / merged this behavior should no longer be happening.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.